# Specifying the return type of an abstract method from a Base Class according to a Sub Class

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism, abstract-class, overriding

I have the following structure:

```
abstract class Base {
        public abstract List<...> Get(); //What should be the generic type?
}

class SubOne : Base {
    public override List<SubOne> Get() {

    }
}

class SubTwo : Base {
    public override List<SubTwo> Get() {

    }
}
```

I want to create an abstract method that returns whatever class the concrete sub class is.  So, as you can see from the example, the method in `SubOne` should return `List<SubOne>` whereas the method in `SubTwo` should return `List<SubTwo>`.

What type do I specify in the signature declared in the Base class ?

---

**[UPDATE]**

Thank you for the posted answers.

The solution is to make the abstract class generic, like such:

```
abstract class Base<T> {
        public abstract List<T> Get();
}

class SubOne : Base<SubOne> {
    public override List<SubOne> Get() {

    }
}

class SubTwo : Base<SubTwo> {
    public override List<SubTwo> Get() {

    }
}
```

Comment: In your update/answer, how would you create a list or collection of the "Base" class that can contain both SubOne and SubTwo objects?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your abstract class should be generic.

```
abstract class Base<T> {
        public abstract List<T> Get(); 
}

class SubOne : Base<SubOne> {
    public override List<SubOne> Get() {

    }
}

class SubTwo : Base<SubTwo> {
    public override List<SubTwo> Get() {
    }
}
```

If you need to refer to the abstract class without the generic type argument, use an interface:

```
interface IBase {
        //common functions
}

abstract class Base<T> : IBase {
        public abstract List<T> Get(); 
}
```

Comment: @recursive hi thanks for your answer - but how would one refer to the abstract class using the interface AND also call the Get method as well?

Comment: What type would you expect it to return?  It seems there's a logical problem calling `Get()` on the interface, since the list element type varies.

Comment: @recursive 
What about:

`abstract class Base{  public abstract List<T> Get<T>(); }`

Wouldn't it be enough to declare the generic type on the method itself, after `Get` --> `Get<T>` ?

Comment: @Legends:  Only if it's meaningful to pass a different parameter types to `Get()` for the same instance.  That doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: @recursive 
I changed the above implementation to declare the type `T` on method level only, which then forces me to implement a `where T: new()` constraint for the declared return type `T`.
This is not the case when declaring type `T` at class level. This is obviously one difference.

Answer (score 4):

```
public abstract class Base<T> 
{       
    public abstract List<T> Get(); 
}

class SubOne : Base<SubOne> 
{
    public override List<SubOne> Get() { return new List<SubOne>(); }
}

class SubTwo : Base<SubTwo> 
{
    public override List<SubTwo> Get() { return new List<SubTwo>(); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public abstract class Base<T> {
  public abstract List<T> Foo();
}

public class Derived : Base<Derived> {   // Any derived class will now return a List of
  public List<Derived> Foo() { ... }     //   itself.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get it to be the specific subclass. You can do this though:

```
abstract class Base<SubClass> {
        public abstract List<SubClass> Get(); 
}
class SubOne : Base<SubOne> {
    public override List<SubOne> Get() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
class SubTwo : Base<SubTwo> {
    public override List<SubTwo> Get() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an situation where your **base class cannot be generic** for various reasons, this method might be useful:

```
abstract class Base {
}
interface IHasGetter<T> {
  List<T> Get();
}
static class HasGetterHelper {
    public static List<T> Get<T>(this T v) where T: IHasGetter<T>  => v.Get();
}
class SubOne : Base, IHasGetter<SubOne> {
    public List<SubOne> Get() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
class SubTwo : Base, IHasGetter<SubTwo> {
    public List<SubTwo> Get() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If you are **unable to add interface to your sub classes**, and still **unable to add generics to the Base type** this method might be useful:
(Unfortunately you cannot make the GetImpl protected, since the helper class is not allowed to be inside the base class)

```
abstract class Base {
    public abstract List<T> GetImpl<T>() where T:Base;
}
static class HasGetterHelper {
    public static List<T> Get<T>(this T v) where T: Base => v.GetImpl<T>();
}
class SubOne : Base {
    public override List<T> GetImpl<T>() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
class SubTwo : Base {
    public override List<T> GetImpl<T>() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In both cases, this will work as expected:

```
class Tester
{
   List<SubOne> TestIt() => new SubOne().Get();
}
```