# Problem with Covariant return types from an abstract method

Tags: c#, covariance, abstract

I’m trying to wrap up a two day beat down on Abstract methods and return type Covariance, I’ve already posted two similar questions and I am eternally grateful to the community for the info provided, I just need one last push to get to the finish line. Here is what I am trying to do: 2 abstract classes, RecruiterBase and CandidateBase, both have concreate implementations of RecruiterA and CandidateA. RecruiterBase has an abstract method to get all recruited candidates returning IQueryable. My implementation of RecruiterA overrides the GetCandidates() method to return IQueryable.

```
public abstract class RecruiterBase
{ 
  // Constructors declared here

  public abstract IQueryable<CandidateBase> GetCandidates();
}

public abstract class CandidateBase
{  
  // Constructors declared here
}
```

and the implementations:

```
public class CandidateA : CandidateBase
{
  // Constructors declared here
}

public class RecruiterA : RecruiterBase
{
  // Constructors declared here

  // ----HERE IS WHERE I AM BREAKING DOWN----
  public override IQueryable<CandidateA> GetCandidates()
  {
     return from c in db.Candidates
            where c.RecruiterId == this.RecruiterId
            select new CandidateA
            {
              CandidateId = c.CandidateId,
              CandidateName = c.CandidateName,
              RecruiterId = c.RecruiterId
            };
  }
}
```

Attempting to complile that throw a compile time error because in my implementation of RecruitreBase the GetCandidates() method returns `IQueryable<CandidateA>` instead of `IQueryable<CandidateBase`>.

After not being able to get the suggestions from a previous question ([Generic return types from abstract/virtual methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330473/generic-return-types-from-abstract-virtual-methods)) to work, I did a LOT more reading, and came across the following question in SO

[How to return subtype in overridden method of subclass in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421851/how-to-return-subtype-in-overridden-method-of-subclass-in-c)

Which finally made me realize what I had been searching for was a way to implement Covariance for my return type. I used Marc Gravell's snippet...

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    public BaseReturnType PolymorphicMethod()
    { return PolymorphicMethodCore();}

    protected abstract BaseReturnType PolymorphicMethodCore();
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override BaseReturnType PolymorphicMethodCore()
    { return PolymorphicMethod(); }

    public new DerivedReturnType PolymorphicMethod()
    { return new DerivedReturnType(); }
}
```

... as the basis for my solution. So now my RecruiterBase and RecruiterA classes look like:

```
public abstract class RecruiterBase
{
  // Constructors declared here

  public IQueryable<CandidateBase> GetCandidates()
  {
     return GetCandidatesCore();
  }

  public abstract IQueryable<CandidateBase> GetCandidatesCore();
}
```

and my implementation...

```
public class RecruiterA : RecruiterBase
{
  // Constructors

  protected override IQueryable<CandidateBase> GetCandidatesCore()
  {
    return GetCandidates();
  }

  public new IQueryable<CandidateA> GetCandidates()
  {
    return from candidates in db.Candidates
           select new CandidateA
           {
             CandidateId = candidates.CandidateId,
             RecruiterId = candidates.RecruiterId
           };
  }
}
```

I was hoping that would finally get me what I was looking for but I got a compile time error in the following code because GetCandidates() cannot implicitly convert CandidateA to CandidateBase:

```
  protected override IQueryable<CandidateBase> GetCandidatesCore()
  {
    return GetCandidates();
  }
```

so I added a cast:

```
  protected override IQueryable<CandidateBase> GetCandidatesCore()
  {
    return ((IQueryable<CandidateBase>)GetCandidates());
  }
```

Everything then compiles but when I actually call GetCandidates() in my controller it returns `IQueryable<CandidateBase>` instead of `IQueryable<CandidateA>`. So I am right back where I started.

If you made it all the way through this and you can help me I'll send you a 12 pack of your favorite beer!

Comment: I tried to add a "shootmenow" tag but I'm still a n00b :)

Comment: what's the type you're working with in your controller? Can you show the code you use there? If you work with RecruiterBase you will never see the variant returning IQueryable of CandidateA (this variant is only available in the derived class).

Comment: @jeroenh, my controller code is pretty straight forward:

RecruiterBase recruiter = new RecruiterA();
IQueryable<CandidateA> candidates = recruiter.GetCandidates();

... which then gets added to the ViewData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justin I am a little bit confused why you need to go through all that trouble.

If you abstract method is of return type **`IQueryable<CandidateBase>`** then that's what you'll get. I don't see a problem with this, since later on you could still cast it back to **CandidateA** or **CandidateB**

So what exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe I am not understanding you question.

**Edit to add:**

Justin, what about this?

```
public abstract class RecruiterBase<T>
    {
        // Constructors declared here

        public abstract IQueryable<CandidateBase> GetCandidates();
    }

    public abstract class CandidateBase
    {
        // Constructors declared here
    }


    public class CandidateA : CandidateBase
    {

    }

    public class RecruiterA : RecruiterBase<RecruiterA>
    {
        // Constructors declared here

        // ----HERE IS WHERE I AM BREAKING DOWN----
        public override IQueryable<CandidateBase> GetCandidates()
        {
            return db.Candidates.Where(cand => cand.RecruiterId == this.RecruiterId)
                         .Select(x => new CandidateA
                                          {
                                             CandidateId = c.CandidateId,
                                             CandidateName = c.CandidateName,
                                             RecruiterId = c.RecruiterId
                                           })
                         .Cast<CandidateBase>()
                         .AsQueryable();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Stan, my implementation of your code does not compile. It fails when calling ".AsQueryable<TempCandidateBase>();". I get an instance argument that a conversion cannot be made from IQueryable<CandidateA> to IEnumerable<CandidateBase>

Comment: Justin, give me a minute I am going to reproduce your code and get back to you.

Comment: Justin. public abstract IQueryable<CandidateBase> GetCandidates(); would not compile in your code example because CandidateBase is a generic class.

Comment: Stan, I apologize for the confusion. You are right that I have CandidateBase marked as abstract, that is from a rabbit hole I went down yesterday that didn't pan out. CandidateBase is not a generic. The <T> should be removed.

Comment: Stan, I edited the code to remove the generic declarations. I'm sorry if that caused you to waste any time. But I'll revert me code and try it if it gets it to work and report back.

Comment: make sure you do .Cast<CandidateBase>().AsQueryable();

Comment: Stan, if I go the generics route then I end up having to intertwining the various generic classes for all my business entities which raised concerns of bloat. This was brought up in my first question (I must have failed to link to that one).
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330473/generic-return-types-from-abstract-virtual-methods

Comment: Justin, look at the above code..there is no need to have generics and the above code will work easily. You are over complicating a simple problem, think to yourself..do you need generics? why do you need generics in this case? these are important questions. You don't need to complicate code because technology allows you to. Keep it simple and you'll have better code down the line.

Comment: Stan you are right, I got away from the generics yesterday, I just pasted in the old code. Yoooder also pointed out below that I've lost my grip on my original problem. Thanks for your code. I'm just going to revisit the whole thing.

Comment: Good thinking Justin. No need to mark me as an answer, thats not important. What's important is good code and good planning ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I think your intentions are good, but the net result is that you're missing the point of polymorphic code and also losing the value.

The purpose of working with objects by their abstract type or by their interfaces is to allow you to work with *any* concrete implementation, without needing to know *any* concrete implementation details.  I think your belief is that by returning concrete types you are producing higher-quality code, when in fact you're beginning to negate the value of the abstract base class by covering up the abstraction.

A properly built set of derived classes should have only very few needs to be addressed by their concrete types; the abstract class should suffice for working with all implementations and should handle the vast majority of work with those classes--the exceptions should be in the minority.

Comment: I'm starting to agree Yoooder, I'm seriously questioning my thought process if what I am trying to do is this out of the ordinary. At least I caught it early in the design process. Thanks for your thoughts on this question and yesterday's.

Comment: No problem; it's normal to try and get something *perfect* only to realize that you went past perfection a few hours ago :)